# How to get real device pixels

Tags: flutter, dart, height, pixel

i have weird results that i want to understand .

1- i have image in my device gallery .

2- I decided to find out the height of an image using image details

3- the given height was 1920

4- Out of curiosity, I wrote the following code

```
Container(
color:Colors.yellow,
width:300,
height:1920, // i know it is big height but it is the same image height 
)
```

5- the output of height was completely bigger than image height

**Question** : why it was bigger ? Isn't it the same height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the flutter uses logical pixel unit to render ui, but you read the image sizes in pixel unit.

You can read more about logical pixel in flutter documents here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/devicePixelRatio.html

To fix that, you need to divide pixel size by devicePixelRatio like this:

```
Container(
    color:Colors.yellow,
    width:300,
    height:1920/MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio, 
)
```

Comment: wow , exactly it was the same . thanks @amir what if i want reverse it ? i mean from logical  pixel to pixel  ?

Comment: @MohammedHamdan This is a simple math, multiply the desired value by devicePixelRatio. Please choose the answer as currect answer if it helps you.